# Verses in Upanishads and vedas to remain Unaffected by bad company

Tags: upanishads, dharma-shastras, spirituality

There is a big hindrance of bad company on the path of spirituality.Most of the scriptures mention to avoid bad company. Swami Sivananda in this context says

> - Aspirants generally complain: “We are doing Sadhana for the last fifteen years. We have not made any solid spiritual progress.”The obvious answer is that they have not totally shunned evil company. *
>
> *Cut off connection ruthlessly. Live alone at all times. Trust in that Immortal Friend who dwells in your heart. He will give you whatever you want. *

I think these statements are direct to the point but its not possible for some people to cut off connections ruthlessly as they have emotional and business attachments with these people. Isn't there any middle road so that people can be with their friends and also join the spiritual path. It is possible to avoid such friends some times but not all times. Are their any verses or advice in upanishads and shastras for such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

A strong willed person can enjoy the company of so called evils. My friends will visit my home and bring meat and chicken dishes from nearby restaurant along with liquor bottles.

We all will sit together, drink and relish the non-veg food.My father will also sit with us and join in debates and discussions.

He never drank liquor in his life nor tasted non-veg. All my friends used to love and respect him for joining in and contributing to make the party a jovial gathering.

My father never deviated from his dharmic path. He preached to all of us to leave this habit of consuming liquor and meat, but never showed any hatred towards my friends or I.

It is all in your mind.

An old sage with his young handsome disciple were travelling by foot. They reached a river bank and had to swim across to the other side to continue their journey.
A young beautiful damsel was standing and asked for help. she said that she has to go a village on the other side of the river but didnt know swimming.

The young monk without hesitation and asking lifted her, swam across, put her down and continued the journey.

After a walk of over a mile, the old sage said  you shouldnt have done it. The young monk asked what?? The old sage said carrying her in your arms.

The young monk replied, "Sir, I put her down a mile back, and why you are carrying her still"??

Why are you getting influenced by the group in which you are also a member. Why dont you influence them???

Comment: This kind of freewheeling citation-free answer is frowned upon in this forum

Answer (score 0):

A popular saying is "Like attracts like " . Companionship is all about the play of nature of Trigun. A predominant tamsik one shall always look for the company of tamsik one. Similarly a rajsik one shall always enjoy the company of rajas predominant persons. 
Same thing applies with sattvik purush but since he happens to be a highly evolved one, endowed with pure knowledge, there is something beyond in him. He roams freely, comes in contact with  so called  good and evil persons  but neither good nor evil acts effect him. Nothing taints him.In every one he sees the manifestation of God. He is totally unattached.The light of sun  helps to spread the fragrance of flowers and also falls on the dirty human waste but nothing affects the sun.

> Jo Rahim  uttam prakriti ka kar sake kusang, Chandan vish vyapat nahi liptat rahat bhujang.

A bottle of wine never flies from ashop to drop in a drunkards house rather he has to rush to the shop and collect after paying the money. 
I am blessed one to have spent some times in **Sivanand Aashram**. The Swami freely used to meet all sections of people. He is never said to be heard of  losing his composure. When he says cut off connection he means the evil traits .He used to say never hate someone hate the evils in him. 
A man of steady wisdom never  get distracted whether in the company of good or evils.

> Udhharet atmanatmanam na atmanam avasadyed ! Aatmaiva hiaatmano bandhuh aatmaiv ripuratmanah  !! Geeta ch 6 sl--5.

Finally it is not the evil one coming to good one  rather it is evil one meeting the evil one.  Regards  , Hare Krishna

Comment: ...it takes a lot of time and practise to be evolved one. You are talking about later stages when a person has achieved a certain maturity in spiritual practises. But my concern is with initial stages and for fledgling aspirants who have to deal with different types of people.Some sadhana, some practises which can help in dealing with this situation.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Use proper [formatting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make your answer more readable. Use blockquote to cite text.

Comment: @pandya --Being quite new to the community as also novish in my smartphone handling  would you please take the trouble to tell me about " Use blockquote to cite text " . Apology for bothering you.

Comment: Ok. Whenever you are quoting the text from Scriptures (Shastras), you should use blockquotes. Go though [formatting guidelines](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to get how to use blockquotes which can be added by ">" operator. You may also note [how your one of the answers has revised](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40112/277). Check the [revisions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/40112/revisions).

Comment: If you're using smart phone, you may try "full site" option (find link at the bottom of web page) to see preview while editing.

Comment: Grateful  ! Hare Krishna